# Polynomial rings in an arbitrary set of indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Recently I was reading an article where the author described a strange polynomial ring that I had never seen before. Here it is (I changed some words):

> $T$ is a set (in the context of the article it is a partially ordered set but it is incidentally, I hope). Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rationals, and form the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ with the elements $t\in T$ as indeterminates. Also there is the following a phrase:
>   If $G\subset T$, then $G\mathbb{Q}[T]$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[T]$.

1. Could you tell me what the object $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ is? I have never met such constructions. Is it something like a ring of polynomials with infinitely many (if $T$ is infinite) variables, i.e. something like an $m$-th tensor power of usual ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Q}[t]$?
2. What is $G\mathbb{Q}[T]$?

Comment: Yes, Q[T] = Q[t1,t2,....] with all the (maybe uncountable) ts in T as variables. GQ[T] is the ideal generated by G: the kernel of the evaluation map that sends every variable in G to 0 (and leaves other variables as variables). The image is an integral domain, so the kernel is prime.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#The_polynomial_ring_in_several_variables

Comment: Just remember that each polynomial involves only finitely many of the indeterminates.

Comment: Ok, but how to build it correctly? There is an article 'Krull implies Zorn', where such a ring is buit to deduce the axiom of choice. So, i need to build the polynomial ring correctly witout using axiom of choice. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer.

It may be easier to replace the word "indeterminates" with the words "elements which are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$".

Definition: Let $F/K$ be a field extension and $x_1,...,x_n \in F$ (where $n \geq 1$). Then a family $(x_1,...,x_n)$ is algebraically independent over $K$ if there does not exist a nonzero polynomial $f(X_1,...,X_n) \in K[X_1,...,X_n] \backslash \lbrace 0 \rbrace $  satisfying $f(x_1,...,x_n)=0$.

Example: Let $T= \lbrace X,Y,Z \rbrace$ where $X,Y,Z$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $K[X,Y,Z]$ is just a polynomial ring in three variables over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then Let $G = \lbrace X,Y \rbrace \subset T $. Then $G\mathbb{Q}[T]$ is just notation for the ideal $(X,Y)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$. It's easy to check that it's prime in this example.